# How to include() all PHP files from a directory, backwards? (most recent first)

Tags: php, foreach, reverse

I have a directory with a hundred HTML files that are ordered alphabetically. They are posts to a blog, and I successfully managed to include() them like this:

```
foreach (glob("posts-en/*.html") as $filename)
{include $filename; }
```

They all display on my website, but I'd like to reverse the order. I search Stack Overflow, and found an apparent solution with "array_reverse". However if I do this:

```
foreach (array_reverse(glob("posts-en/*.html") as $filename))
{include $filename;}
```

It doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: For what it's worth, nowhere in the [glob()](https://php.net/glob) manual page it's stated that files are ordered by date. Actually, it says explicitly that they're sorted alphabetically by default.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that. In my case, the date is in the filename, hence, "alphabetically" and "by date" are the same here. So in other words, I would like reverse-alphabetical order. I just edited the question

Comment: Your brackets are misplaced. I'm surprised this code actually runs :-?

Comment: I can't seem to find where I put wrong brackets

Comment: Is that your real code? It triggers a parse error for me: https://3v4l.org/hQfFd#v8.1.8 - You need to apply `array_reverse()` to an array, but you currently apply it to the inner expression of the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: That is my real code and I'm getting the same error. I asked this question because I couldn't figure out how to syntax it properly. I don't know if I'm taking the right approach

Comment: The `$foo as $bar` syntax only makes sense in a foreach loop. You cannot do `array_reverse($foo as $bar)` any more than you can do `echo $a as $b`. You want `array_reverse($foo) as $bar`, not `array_reverse($foo as $bar)`.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, that was my mistake! It solved the problem and my website now works as intended. I wish I could choose yours as the answer but the thread has been closed.

Comment: Don't worry. Such answer wouldn't help anyone else. The parse error is not even mentioned in the question.